# Syntax error using ast.literal_eval(open("filename").readlines()[0]) in python

Tags: python, import, syntax-error

When I try to run my code and import an array from another file I keep getting a Syntax Error saying:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 21, in <module>
    passwords = ast.literal_eval(open("passwords.txt").readlines()[0])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [‘test’]
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The piece ['test'] is the contents of the external file "passwords.txt", however what confuses me is that in the following code if I include only the first 2 variables the code runs perfectly fine but when the second is added it throws an error (also the file contents is the same in all of the variables)

```
adjectives = ast.literal_eval(open("Adjectives.txt").readlines()[0])
nouns = ast.literal_eval(open("Nouns.txt").readlines()[0])
passwords = ast.literal_eval(open("passwords.txt").readlines()[0])
usernames = ast.literal_eval(open("usernames.txt").readlines()[0])
```

The only other related new code is this:

```
def WOPR():
    login = raw_input("Username: ")
    login_password = raw_input("Password: ")
    login_password = psudo_encrypt(login_password)
    for name in usernames:
        if name == login:
            for word in passwords:
                if word == login_password:
                    print("Greetings " + login)
                    play(true, login)
                else:
                    print("Incorrect Password \n-------Connection Terminated-------")
        elif login == "Joshua":
            print("Greetings Professor Falken \nWould you like to play a game?")
            play(true, "Professor")
        else:
            WOPR()
```

Anyone any idea what could be causing this? Have I missed a really obvious syntax issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: *also the file contents is the same in all of the variables*...are you sure? Otherwise this would not be possible: *if I include only the first 2 variables the code runs perfectly fine*. Please show content so we can reproduce.

Comment: Generally you should not try to cram so much into a single line of code. Use variables judiciously to store intermediate results. Also, `read()` returns one line at a time. No need to read the entire file.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for the advice, I sort of get that, but this isn't anything big, it's more just a proof of concept I'm doing for myself so it won't have any more than about 10 strings in each array so nothing too massive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[‘test’]
 ^    ^
```

The two characters I've marked are curly apostrophes (`‘’`), not straight apostrophes (`'`). You probably got them by copying and pasting code from a web site, or by editing your code in a text editor that isn't intended for working with code.

Replace those characters with normal apostrophes.